# Close java PreparedStatement and ResultSets

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

The code below  does not compile, because both PreparedStatement.close() and ResultSet.close() throw a java.sql.SQLException. So do I add a try/catch block to the finally clause? Or move the close statements into the try clause? Or just not bother calling close?

```
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
  ps = conn.createStatement(myQueryString);
  rs = ps.executeQuery();
  // process the results...
} catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
  log.error("an error!", e);
  throw new MyAppException("I'm sorry. Your query did not work.");
} finally {
  ps.close();
  rs.close();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of the new feature introduced in Java 7, [try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

For example...

```
try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.createStatement(myQueryString)) {
    // bind parameters
    try (ResultSet rs = rs = ps.executeQuery()) {}
        // process the results...
    }
} catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
    log.error("an error!", e);
    throw new MyAppException("I'm sorry. Your query did not work.");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use try-with-resources blocks (introduced in Java 7), which will automatically close resources for you.

Here is the equivalent code you posted, rewritten with a try-with-resource block:

```
try(PreparedStatement ps = conn.createStatement(myQueryString)) 
{
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    // process the results...
} catch(SQLException e) {
    log.error("an error!", e);
    throw new MyAppException("I'm sorry. Your query did not work.");
}
```

Note:
It is not necessary to call `close()` on the ResultSet here, because according to the [`Statement.close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close()) doc:

> When a Statement object is closed, its current ResultSet object, if one exists, is also closed.

Answer (score 1):

A few ways to do this.

First and the simplest, if you are using Java 7 then implement [try-with-resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) as what mentioned in other answers.

Second way you can just add a try/catch to the `finally` block. Suggest to close `ResultSet` first, followed by `Statement` and finally `Connection`.

```
finally {
    if (rs != null) {
        rs.close();
    }
    if (ps != null) {
        ps.close();
    }
}
```

Third way is to use external library eg [Commons DbUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/) which takes care of all the closing for you.

```
finally {
    org.apache.commons.dbutils.DbUtils.closeQuietly(rs);
    org.apache.commons.dbutils.DbUtils.closeQuietly(ps);
}
```